# Rails search many to many

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

I've created a Rails app based on many to many relationship. With three models : medic, lab, lab_medic, I tried to build search function on lab_medic table.

Here's what I've got so far:

lab_medic.rb

```
belongs_to :medic
belongs_to :lab

def self.search(search)
    if search
      q = "%#{search}%"

      joins(:medic).where('lab_medics.medic.anamnesa LIKE ? OR 
             medics.anamnesa LIKE ?',q,q)
    else
      scoped
    end
end
```

medic.rb

```
has_many :lab_medics
has_many :labs, :through => lab_medics
```

lab.rb

```
has_many :lab_medics
has_many :medics, :through => lab_medics
```

lab_medics_controller.rb

```
def search
    base_lab_medic = LabMedic.search(params[:search])
    @lab_medics_count = base_lab_medic.count
    @lab_medics = base_lab_medic.paginate(:page => params[:page])

    render :index
end
```

lab_medics/index.html.erb

```
    <div class="controls">
      <%= form_tag(search_lab_medics_path, :method => "get", id: "search-form") do %>
        <div class="input-group">       
          <%= text_field_tag :search, params[:search], placeholder: "Search Anamnesa", class: "form-control", id: "date" %>
           <span class="input-group-addon ">
             <i class="fa fa-search"></i>
           </span>     
        </div>
      <% end %>
   </div>
```

When i tried to search 'anamnesa' on lab_medic, i've got an error. How to fix my search function?

**Edit**

lab_medics/index.html.erb

```
<table class="table table-striped table-hover" id="lab_medics">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Date</th>
      <th>Diagnosis</th>
      <th>Lab Test</th>
      <th>Price</th>
      <th>Result</th>
      <th>Action</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody id="lab_medics2">
    <% if @lab_medics.count > 0 %>
      <% @lab_medics.each do |lab_medic| %>
        <tr id="lab_medic-<%= lab_medic.id %>">
          <tr>
            <td><%= lab_medic.medic.date %></td>
            <td><%= lab_medic.medic.anamnesa %></td>
            <td><%= lab_medic.lab.name %></td>
            <td><%= lab_medic.lab.price %></td>
            <td><%= lab_medic.result %></td>
            <td>
              <div class="btn-group">
                <button class="btn btn-primary btn-sm dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"><span class="fa fa-gear"></span> Action <span class="caret"></span></button>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu right-edge">
                  <li><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_lab_medic_path(lab_medic), remote: true, class: "separated-link" %></li>
                  <li><%= link_to 'Delete', lab_medic_path(lab_medic), method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' }, class: "separated-link" %></li>
                </ul>
              </div>  
            </td>
          </tr>
        </tr>
      <% end %>
    <% else %>
      <tr>
        <td colspan="6" align="center">No medic data found!</td>
      </tr>
    <% end %>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

I want to search anamnesa from medic model on lab_medic table

Comment: What errors are you getting?

Comment: This my error => PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR: missing FROM-clause entry for table "medic" LINE 1: ...rds"."id" = "lab_medics"."medic_id" WHERE (lab_medics... ^ : SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "lab_medics" INNER JOIN "medics" ON "medics"."id" = "lab_medics"."medic_id" WHERE (lab_medics.medic.anamnesa LIKE '%Maag%' OR medics.anamnesa LIKE '%Maag%')

Comment: The problem is here -> 'lab_medics.medic.anamnesa'.

In order to access a table column value you should do 'table_name.column'. 

To help you more, please provide all your table columns and what you wanna get from your query.

Comment: I've edit data for my question. That's table of lab_medic

Comment: <td><%= lab_medic.medic_record.anamnesa %></td>    Is this right? It wouldn't be:

<td><%= lab_medic.medic.anamnesa %></td>            ?

Comment: Ups sorry that's my code before i change to medic :) Edited

Comment: Does labs table have an 'anamnesa' column too?

Comment: No. labs table only have name and price, lab_medics only have medic_id, lab_id and result

Answer (score 0):

Since `anamnesa` is a column of `medics` table, you should define your `search` method inside your `Medic` model like following:

```
def self.search(param)
    self.where("anamnesa like '%#{param}%'")
end
```

Another way of doing the same is using scopes which could be:

```
scope :search, -> (param) { where("anamnesa like '%#{param}%'") }
```

From within your controller you should call:

```
search = medic_params[:search]
medics = Medic.search(search)
```

*Please notice I used strong parameters (at `medic_params[:search]`) so that SQL injection is avoided. You can read more about it [strong parameters here](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#strong-parameters).*

Answer (score -1):

In this case you should use The [has_and_belongs_to_many](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-and-belongs-to-many-association) Association

Comment: This is wrong. `has_many :through` is already being used, and it is the better solution.

Comment: he just created it and just tried to do something, so this is not difficult to refactor it. I think we have to write code in right way and write clear code. If we'll writing bad small code it create many misunderstanding.

Comment: This isn't about being unwilling to change it, it's *already correct*. Changing it to HABTM would make it worse.

Comment: we just have different points of views on this issue. But HABTM will remove one step in association. model `lab_medic.rb` not needed in his case. He has broken `search` method, and it should be in `lab.rb` model.